# AJAX causes inconsistent renderings

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular2 and have a template which uses ngFor to display a div DIV1 if a flag is true else to display another div DIV2.
This flag is retrieved with AJAX from the server in the ngOnInit() method of the component.

The problem is that if the flag is initialized to true bue retrieved as false then when the page is rendered initially DIV1 is rendered and very fast it disappears and DIV2 is displayed. This is annoying and the user can notice the temporary inconsistent view rendering (especially if the AJAX call is slow).

It is a simple case and therefore I don't provide an example since here I don't want to test if the aforementioned functionality works.

The question is how should I treat this and similar cases so that only the correct divs should be displayed?

Comment: Not really an angular2 question (: You could hide by default, or use DIV0 that looks similar to other divs until ajax is resolved...

Comment: Mostly interested in an Angular2 approach, e.g. if there is an interceptor to show a spinner. Added the javascript tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another flag that indicates if the value was already retrieved and wrap your content in an `*ngIf` or use `hidden`

```
<div *ngIf="realValueRetrieved">
<!-- <div [hidden]="realValueRetrieved"> -->
  <div *ngIf="flag">
  </div>
</div>
```

and set `realValueRetrieved` to `true` if it is `false`, otherwise don't change it.

Actually there are unlimited ways to handle that and it's up to you what you actually want. Display a spinner, display nothing, use an animation when the value arrives and the content is revealed, ....

Comment: So either hiding the content (directly or indirectly) until I get the real value or progressively rendering the view components. Until now I have followed the 2nd approach but I think the 1st one is better.